# How to create a useful Polars Dataframe from a numpy structured array?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, hdf5, python-polars

I'm converting an application from Pandas to Polars in search of better scalability and performance.
My app reads data from an hdf5 compound dataset (using h5py) into a numpy structured array from which I create the Pandas dataframe directly as follows,

```
# dset is the hdf5 compound Dataset
np_struct_array = np.empty(dset.shape, dset.dtype)
dset.read_direct(np_struct_array)
df=pd.DataFrame(np_struct_array, dset.dtype)
```

The dtype of the numpy structured array depends on the h5 dataset being read, but a typical example would something like

```
[('SID', '<i8'), ('G', '<i8'), ('C', '<i8'), ('D', '<f8'), ('DOMAIN_ID', '<i8')]
```

This is super fast and the dataframe uses the column names and types from the numpy structured array directly

When I switch to Polars and use the same approach, the resulting Polars dataframe is a single column dataframe of type object which is not what I need - for example the schema arising from the above numpy structured array is `{'column_0': Object}`

I can do the following and get the dataframe I need, but the performance sucks - 10x slower than Pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
      field_name: np_struct_array[field_name] for field_name in np_struct_array.dtype.fields
    }
)
```

So my question is what is the fastest/most efficient way to get the hdf5 compound dataset into a Polars dataframe? Is there a better way to use the numpy structured array with Polars for example? I could continue to read the data into a Pandas dataframe and then create a Polars dataframe from that, but I think that will create a copy which I'd rather avoid since the data can be big.

Any advice will be gratefully received.

Doug

Comment: An example could help. It looks like the issue you're describing is: `pl.DataFrame(np.array([('Rex', 5, 81.), ('Fido', 5, 27.)], dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('age', '<i4'), ('weight', '<f4')]))` compared to a regular numpy array `pl.DataFrame(np.array([('Rex', 5, 81.), ('Fido', 5, 27.)]))`?

Comment: The dtype of the np_struct_array in the snippet provided depends on the table being read from the h5 file, but a typical dtype would be something like [('SID', '<i8'), ('G', '<i8'), ('C', '<i8'), ('D', '<f8'), ('DOMAIN_ID', '<i8')]

Comment: related? https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3520

Comment: @FObersteiner - Related, but not an answer.....

Comment: It appears that polars doesn't know what a structured array is. You could do a feature request for it to be supported. Perhaps a faster workaround than what you're currently doing would be to loop through the data types and one data type at a time do a `pl.from_numpy(structured_to_unstructured(CHUNK_OF_NPARRAY))` and then hstack those together.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor - Thanks. I came to the same conclusion and commented about numpy structured array support in the Polars hdf5 feature request. I'm currently working through slicing out each unique datatype from the structured array and then concatenating the dataframes at the end (instead of hstack). Some of my structured arrays include nested arrays and if I create a Polars dataframe from those the creation is extremely slow for some reason so I have to expand them first and then add them to get reasonable performance......

Comment: Polars has a structured array now: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/8943?ref=blog.lancedb.com but I can't figure out how to cast np.array to polars array :(

Answer (score 5):

FYI: I added [native support](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/8620) for initialising a polars DataFrame from numpy structured/record arrays yesterday, and it will be available in the upcoming `0.17.12` release. (Native support for *exporting* from polars to numpy structured/record arrays is also about to merge).

Comment: Thanks Alexander!!!!  I'll take a look when 0.17.12 drops - that should allow me to remove a chunk of pre-processing code from my project

Comment: Good stuff :)  FYI: the export code was also [merged](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/8628), so you'll soon be able to init from _and_ export to structured arrays cleanly.

Comment: How about if I have a `.map_elements` that gives me a bunch of NumPy arrays - how do I cast them to Polars Array? `data = data.with_columns(pl.col(new_column).cast(pl.Array(pl.Float32, 1024)))` did not work and just gives me a `polars.exceptions.ComputeError: cannot cast 'Object' type`.

Comment: It is possible `my_list = [npa.tolist() for npa in data[new_column]]; data = data.with_columns(pl.Series(new_column, my_list, dtype=pl.Array(pl.Float32, 1024)))` but then you can't save them afterwards because `pyo3_runtime.PanicException: not yet implemented: Writing FixedSizeList to parquet not yet implemented`